# mutate_at vs. quosure with string arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, quosure

When a parameter of a function is a string rather than a quosure (e.g. from a Shiny UI) I can think of 2 options to use it in a `dplyr::mutate` call:

1. **string -> quosure**

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   var <- "am"
   mtcars %>% mutate(!!rlang::sym(var) := !!rlang::sym(var) + 1)
   ```
2. **mutate_at**

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   var <- "am"
   mtcars %>% mutate_at(var, funs(. + 1))
   ```

Is there any reason to prefer one of the other? Are there any border cases which I may not be aware of? For consistency I want to stick to one option and I need to decide which one I should choose. Option 2 needs less dependencies, but I want to eb sure that both variants are indeed identical.

Comment: Conceptually, using `mutate_at` limits your options to updating one or more existing variables whereas `mutate` also allows you to add new variables, as far as I know. There may be other differences, but this one might be relevant, too.